# Section name appears after the wrong table

Tags: floats

So I am writing a paper in document class `article`, and my section name (Appendix) appears after the wrong table.

More specifically, I have some tables in "Figures and Tables" section, and I have few more tables in Appendix section. As you can predict, there are no texts in these sections except those in tables. This is what is happening:

Preamble is

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}    
\usepackage{tabularx}     
\usepackage{afterpage}     
\usepackage{pdflscape}     
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}     
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}     
\usepackage{subcaption} \usepackage{float}
```

---

```
\section{Figures and Tables}
\input{table_1.tex}
\input{table_2.tex}
\input{table_3.tex}
\input{table_4.tex}
\section{Appendix}
\input{table_5.tex}
\input{table_6.tex}
```

Table 2 code is

```
\begin{landscape}
\advance\hoffset by -2cm 
\advance\voffset by 1cm
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Something}

\begin{tabular}{l*{8}{c}}


\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Table 4 code is

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Something}
\begin{tabular}{l  c  c  c  c }
\hline\hline

\end{table}
```

And, table 5 code is

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{something\label}
\begin{tabular}{l  c  c  c  c }
\hline\hline

\end{table}
```

I want the "Appendix" to appear after table 4 but it appears after table 2. Table 2 is a landscape table (define in `table_2.tex`}.

When I change table 4 to landscape, then Appendix appears right after table 4 which is what I want. But I can not have table 4 in landscape as it is a long table.

Can anybody suggest how to fix it? I did try `\pagebreak`, `\newpage` and `\vspace` options but they didn't work. Thanks!

I used the float package, and I am used table environment with [H] option, some of the tables are still used with [htbp] option. Now Appendix appears after table 4 which is what I want. But there are two problems now. First, page after table 2 (the landscape one) is blank. And, table 4 (the one before the Appendix) is out of the page. It looks like float package has some effect here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a minimum working example...

Comment: Try to load the `float` package and put your tables in `table` environments using the `[H]` position option. Is it better? If not provide a full minimum working example, please.

Comment: It did shift the Appendix right before table 5, which is what I want. However, the led to two new problems. First, the page after table 2 (the landscape one) is blank for no apparent reason. And second, table 4 (the one before the appendix) is distorted and outside the page.

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding the code of your preamble and minimal codes of your tables so that the problem takes place? (PS: you should @username when starting your comments if you want the concerned person to be notified about your comment.)

Comment: It sounds like you want `\clearpage` before `\section{Appendix}` but without a real example hard to be sure

Comment: Another method: `\FloatBarrier` of package `placeins` right before `\section{Appendix}` stops tables from floating past the appendix title.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek Thanks a lot! This works perfect! I can't believe I spent hours fixing it. Even though I had found a way around it after several hours of work, and trial and error; that wasn't the ideal situation.

Comment: You don't have to load `caption` twice.

Answer (score 4):

There are several methods to deal with float placement control, see the comments to the question, e.g.:

- [Comment of Ludovic C.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133946/section-name-appears-after-the-wrong-table?noredirect=1#comment302600_133946): Package `float` with placement specifier `H` sets the floats right "here" without floating.
- [Comment of David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133946/section-name-appears-after-the-wrong-table?noredirect=1#comment302685_133946): `\clearpage` before `\section{Appendix}` forces the floats to be output and starts a new page.
- [My comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133946/section-name-appears-after-the-wrong-table?noredirect=1#comment302690_133946): `\FloatBarrier` of package `placeins` right before `\section{Appendix}` stops tables from floating past the appendix title.
- If a section contains only floats without text, then floating is not really needed. The Float captions can be set without the floating environments (e.g., `table`) with `\captionof{table}` of package `capt-of` or the more powerful `caption`.

Comment: The OP is happy with `\FloatBarrier` of package `placeins` (see [Chandan's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133946/section-name-appears-after-the-wrong-table/134048#comment302729_133946)). Therefore I have spend the time writing the answer.